# Dropdown menu link show/hide issue

Tags: jquery

Two issues needs to be done.

1. Dropdown shouldn't appear when I click on check box inside the Menu Item container.
2. Dropdown should be hide when I click outside of the menu anywhere in the page.

Here is my Jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/awaises/5FfgZ/

Flowing is my code.

```
HTML
<div class="check_dropdown">
<input type="checkbox"> <a href="#" class="menu_item">Menu Item</a>
 <ul class="leads_menu">
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>

CSS
.check_dropdown{
    background:#edecec;
    padding:2px;
    display:inline-block;
    }
.leads_menu {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    color: #000;
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#edecec;
}

jQuery
$(function() {
    $(".check_dropdown").each(function() {
        if ($(this).find(".menu_item").length > 0) {
            $(this).mousedown(function() {
                $(this).find(".leads_menu").stop(true, true).slideToggle();
            });          
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have updated your fiddle ([Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/5FfgZ/3/)) to check for the following:

1. If the clicked element is a checkbox then prevent the dropdown menu from showing up.
2. Made clicking anywhere in the HTML web page to trigger the dropdown to hide.

The changes are at JS level: http://jsfiddle.net/5FfgZ/3/

```
$(function() {
    var menuClicked = false; //Check if user opened the dropdown
    $(document).on('click', function(){
        if(menuClicked){
            menuClicked = false;   
            return;
        }
        if($(".leads_menu").css('display') != 'none'){
            $(".leads_menu").stop(true, true).slideToggle();
        }
    });
    $(".check_dropdown").each(function(e) {
        if ($(this).find(".menu_item").length > 0) {
            $(this).mousedown(function(e) {
                if($(e.target).attr('type') == 'checkbox') return; //Check if element clicked is a checkbox.
                $(this).find(".leads_menu").stop(true, true).slideToggle();
                menuClicked = true;
            });          
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may be you want

```
$(document).click(function(){
 $(".leads_menu").hide();
});

$(".menu_item").click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [fiddle with a working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/5FfgZ/1/)

```
<ul class="check_dropdown">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"> <a href="#" class="menu_item">Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="leads_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox"> <a href="#" class="menu_item">Menu Item</a>
        <ul class="leads_menu">
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sub Menu</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

$(function() {
  $(".menu_item").click(function(e) {
    $(this).siblings('.leads_menu').stop(true, true).slideToggle();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind an event to the document or window to catch the next click/mousedown outside the dropdown to close it.
jquery is giving you a simple method for this called *one*

```
$(window).one('mousedown', function() { ... });
```

i've changed your fiddle, so that you can have a look at it.
also you have to prevent the propagation of the mousedown-event. otherwise it will go to your window-object and call the one-binded method.

http://jsfiddle.net/5FfgZ/2/